# Four Momentum in an Isotropic and Homogeneous Universe

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, astronomy, space-expansion

We define the four-momentum of a particle by $p^\mu = (E, \mathbf{p})$, where $E$ is energy and $\mathbf{p}$ the three momentum of the particle. In cosmology, we conventionally use the Friedmann-Robertson-Walker (FRW) metric to describe an *isotropic* and *homogeneous* Universe. Note that here I've scaled the quantities so that $c = \frac{h}{2\pi} = 1$.

I was told in lectures that the assumptions of isotropy and homogeneity meant that $\partial_i P^\mu = 0$. Can someone explain clearly why this is?